# Foreach loop to complete table columns

Tags: php, html

I'm stuck, again... I'm trying to make more than 1 foreach loop for each result from my database and trying to populate each column with their respective results.

What I have so far:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM quemindicaresultados
                WHERE ra_aluno like '****'";

        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();

$nomeIndicado = array_column($result, 'nome_indicado');
$indicadoInscrito = array_column($result, 'indicado_inscrito');

foreach ($result as $value) {
  echo '<tr>';

    foreach($nomeIndicado as $sera) {
      echo '<td>'. $sera .'</td>';
    }

    foreach($indicadoInscrito as $sera2) {
      echo '<td style="text-align: center;">'. $sera2 .'</td>';

    }
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Ok, this looks great right? (I know it doesn't) Sadly, it generates more than 1 result and repeat itself A LOT. The result of this it's something like this:

```
    Nome  | Indicado Inscrito
Andrielle Barboza Bernart | Fabiana Machado de Lima | Maiara Ferreira | Indica��o Inv�lida | Sim | Sim
Andrielle Barboza Bernart | Fabiana Machado de Lima | Maiara Ferreira | Indica��o Inv�lida | Sim | Sim
Andrielle Barboza Bernart | Fabiana Machado de Lima | Maiara Ferreira | Indica��o Inv�lida | Sim | Sim
```

To clarify, what I want should look like this:

```
  Nome                    | Indicado Inscrito
Andrielle Barboza Bernart | Indica��o Inv�lida  
Fabiana Machado de Lima   | Sim  
Maiara Ferreira           | Sim
```

I know it's something wrong with the loop, I just can't understand what and why, could someone help me please?

EDIT 1: added sql select to clarify the `$result`

Comment: Is this linked to any other code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that `$result` is the number of rows required and both `$nomeIndicado` and `$indicadoInscrito` contain the same number of items as $results.

```
$nomeIndicado = array_column($result, 'nome_indicado');
$indicadoInscrito = array_column($result, 'indicado_inscrito');

for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++) {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'. $nomeIndicado[$i] .'</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">'. $indicadoInscrito[$i] .'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: can you please clarify what `$<count` actually does? It returns me syntax error

Comment: @FelipeBueno Sorry I missed the i out of $i, bascially saying while $i < number of elements in $result. I have edited my post. Too much js recently. Missed some $ out inside the arrays too. post should be fine now.

Comment: I must thank you for this! Forgot completely about `for` loops. Cheers!